# It is possible use a *.dll generated from a Swift Binding project?

Tags: c#, dll, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

I was given a new library *.framework in Swift 5 from an external client and I'm trying to integrate this lib in our Xamarin.iOS project; I made it creating a new binding project and following the MS documentation steps, but I was wondering if it possible add this library using its *.dll instead the binding project in order to minimise the app size and complexity.

I created the *.dll successfully but I got these errors after add the *.dll lib and delete the binding project references:

**MT5209: Error: framework not found dobSDK. Native linking.**

**MTOUCH: Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202)**

**clang: Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

I also tried adding the .framework to as native reference but got this one:

**can't process a mix of dylibs and frameworks**

I'm missing any link? reference? lib? mtouch argument?

I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong or if its even possible, I've just created few binding projects and never using it *.dll instead the full project.

any help or hint will be welcome.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi , I have no idea about using .dll file in Xamarin iOS . Maybe you can have a try to bind swift library refer to this article from Lucas Teixeira . https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, I did and it worked, but now I'm struggling with the .dll files; it's strange, should work since it did it with the binding project it self.

Comment: Ok , doc of xamarin iOS not shows how to  bind .dll project . I think maybe there will be some differences in iOS platform . If solution later will share here to discuss .

Comment: Do you have access to the framework source code ? Can you please provide more information on how you created API definitions, that will help answer the question. Thanks.